# PutBucketReplication operation: Access Denied using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Below are my configurations and I'm still getting Access Denied excpetion while trying to do PutBucketReplication from a lambda.

Replication role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<source bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<source bucket>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<destination bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<destination bucket>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<source bucket>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<destination bucket>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Lambda Role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:<source account>:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:<source account>:log-group:/aws/lambda/PutReplicationFunction:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Source bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<source account>:role/service-role/PutReplicationFunction-role-pugxea1r"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<source bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<source bucket>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

IAM pass role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Input request:

```
client.put_bucket_replication(
        Bucket='<source bucket>',
        ReplicationConfiguration={
            'Role': '<iam role used for replication>',
            'Rules': [
                {
                    "Priority": 0,
                    "DeleteMarkerReplication": {"Status": "Disabled"},
                    "Filter": {"Prefix": ""},
                    'Status': 'Enabled',
                    'Destination': {
                        'Bucket': 'arn:aws:s3:::<destination bucket>'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    )
```

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketReplication operation: Access Denied",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "requestId": "10515e45-992c-46bf-a20d-cce84c47dbb7",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.put_bucket_replication(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

I also tried adding the bucket policy on destination account, but it is still not working
Destination bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Set permissions for objects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<iam role used for replication>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<destination bucket>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Set permissions on bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<iam role used for replication>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<destination bucket>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to  make sure that the Lambda IAM role has the `iam:PassRole` permission. So you could modify the current Lambda policy to the following:

```
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:<source account>:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:<source account>:log-group:/aws/lambda/PutReplicationFunction:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }, 
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the missing piece for me.